# Attributes value is not intercepted by the interceptor in EJB

Tags: java, web, ejb, weblogic12c

I have injected my simple pojo ejb into web service interface and trying to intercept the method simple pojo by using the EJB interceptor but issue is that instance of injected pojo will hold the value that is setted in earlier request of web service

How to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do u get any errors ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: not any error but not intercepting the POJO attribute value.

Comment: Could be something wrong in the code ? Did that code worked before ? Or did you try to have all in one jar ..just to debug ?

Comment: in single jar, it is running well. However, our requirements make it two separate jars.